# Email filtering and labelling for team

Tags: email, self-hosted, cloud-service, workflow

Currently I have the following workflow:

1. Receiving email notices and alerts from various sources.
2. Using Gmail, define filters and labels to automatically label the emails
   according to Source, Type, if action needed.
3. If action needed, manually review and add label

This works fine when I'm one person. Now with more people, I like to extend this workflow to a team.

So, is there a cloud service that can

1. Forward all the emails to the service
2. Allow a team of different people to have separate access
3. Filter the incoming email according to labels
4. Add/Update labels by any team members
5. Able to append comments to each email (something like [comments in a Trello card](https://d2k1ftgv7pobq7.cloudfront.net/meta/u/res/images/41b5d89ad26cc5fe4aac4065fb80c81d/board-activity_section.jpg))
6. Able to filter, search email based on content, label (similar to what Gmail search can do)

Cost: Not more than $30/month for 10 people.

Alternatively, I'm also open to consider plugin or self hosted application that can provide the above requirement.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself so I put it in a comment rather than an answer, but maybe Front (www.frontapp.com) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Ctouw it appears to be another helpdesk type application that could have the features we need. However we have many users that just need to view and access less frequently, so per user pricing don't fits well. Thanks for suggesting!